# lubridate convert format_ISO8601 year-Wweek (2022-W01)

Tags: r, lubridate, iso8601

I scraped data from RKI. In a table the dates are transmitted ISO8601 compliant. The goal is to visualize later the data with ggplot in R. Unfortunately ggplot can not handle this format. Example from the Date Column.

```
library(lubridate)

w <- paste("2021-W", 46:52, sep = "")
w1 <-c("2022-W01")
ww <-c(w,w1)

df_ww<- format_ISO8601(as.Date(ww,format = "%YYYY-W%w“))

str(ww)
 chr [1:8] "2021-W46" "2021-W47" "2021-W48" "2021-W49" "2021-W50" "2021-W51" "2021-W52" "2022-W01“

df_ww
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df_ww <- as.Date(paste0(gsub("\\D", "", ww), 1), format="%Y%U%u")
```

**Output:**

```
> df_ww
[1] "2021-11-15" "2021-11-22" "2021-11-29" "2021-12-06" "2021-12-13" "2021-12-20" "2021-12-27" "2022-01-03"
```

---

**Update:**

Ok, what about:

```
df_ww <- gsub("W", "", ww)
```

**Output:**

```
[1] "2021-46" "2021-47" "2021-48" "2021-49" "2021-50" "2021-51" "2021-52" "2022-01"
```

Comment: thanks but target must be "2021-52“  "2022-01“ like year-week

Comment: Ok, I've updated my post. What do you think?

Comment: in the table looks the result good, but ggplot can´t handle the format

Comment: Can you copy the ggplot code?